# Help needed in the [applications] tag

Tags: discussion, tag-cleanup

The [applications](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/applications) tag is only supposed to be used for questions that are about Android applications in general. Unfortunately, that hasn't always happened.

Here are a few of the misuses:

- the [development](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/development) tag tells people not to use it, so they use "applications" instead
- the question is about a single application, which may or may not have its own tag already
- none of the tags the asker wants exists, or they don't really want to add any, and it's almost always listed as a tag suggestion, so they add it because they're forced to add a tag
- there has been a question or two that use *other* definitions of "application", mainly "an act of putting to use"

Not to mention the "application recommendation" questions we're really prefer not to have.

There are **a lot** of questions in this tag, and I'd estimate at least a third of these (if not more) are misuses of the tag.

So, if you're of a mind to help with some housecleaning, please do so. Don't worry if you don't have sufficient privs. Editing suggestions are very helpful too. (Moderators can't be everywhere at once, you know. Plus you can get free reputation points.)

One thing that would help would be to delete some of the large number of closed questions with this tag. Try [this search](https://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=[applications]+closed%3A1) to find them.

- 2012-04-24: 696
- 2012-04-30: 599
- 2012-05-24: 568
- 2012-07-06: 601
- 2013-09-12: 817

It's getting worse.

Comment: Minor note: I just deleted a misspelled synonym (`aplications`). Better to let those just die.

Comment: Man, just deleting the giant collection of closed development questions seems like it will make a pretty big dent. A **ton** of them are tagged with `applications`.

Comment: If you want to more easily find closed questions tagged "applications", here's a [search URL](http://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=[applications]+closed%3A1)

Answer (score -1):

I'd like to ask for opinions about the following idea:

ATM is not possible to see if a question that is taged [application](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/application) was already reviewed. Therefore my motivation to review the application tag is very low. I suggest we retag every question that has been reviewed either with a more approbiate application tag or rename [application](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/application) to [android-application](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/android-application). If the [application](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/application) count is zero [android-application](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/android-application) can become [application](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/application) again.