# Feature request to avoid code on AE from novice users

Tags: discussion, feature-request

After going through this [post](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1239/how-to-stop-users-from-posting-development-questions-on-android-enthusiasts) thoroughly I am asking for a feature which may be valid/invalid.(based on the moderator to accept it)

I prefer something more or less the ability to post a question should be unlocked only on the user receiving the Informed Badge.

As the user is forced to read the about page it can indirectly reduce the clutter from the user side as he/she will not post any coding/development related on AE .

[image: In the below post you can clearly see that the user is a first timer with just 1 rep and also he is missing the informed badge making sense that he hasn't read the about page and posted question relating to code]

I have also observed that many first timers posting the question with code or relating to development always lag the informed badge so I suggest to have this feature.
If anyone has any other valid method to avoid this then please feel free to suggest.

Simply flagging the post for the moderator as off the topic is not a better option as we have to avoid code/development related posts on AE for the future as well.

Comment: While I am extremely interested in combating this, I fear that clueless people will simply scroll through the About page to get the badge, refusing to read.  And new users asking good questions will have this stumbling block in their way -- the more barriers to using a site, even a minor one like this, the more users simply don't bother and go elsewhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Similar requests have been made at [Meta Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com) ([example](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188309/force-new-users-to-go-through-animated-tutorial-before-they-post-for-the-first-t?lq=1)) and have generally been dismissed.

Generally speaking, I don't think the Stack Exchange folks want to be so draconian in putting barriers in front of people who want to ask questions. That said, they have added plenty of advise, warnings, etc., and people still ask bad questions. Besides, when was the last time you actually read a terms of service document that you were "required" to read before using a site/program/etc.? Why wouldn't people simply scroll to the bottom of the screen in order to get ask their question as soon as possible.

I'd love to see fewer development questions here, but I'm not convinced that your solution is the way to do it.