# Tag cleanup for October, 2013

Tags: discussion, tag-cleanup

The following tags are overly broad, misapplied, *meta tags* [<sup>1</sup>](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1284/what-are-meta-tags)[<sup>2</sup>](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/), ambiguous or are otherwise problematic.

- [untagged](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged)
  These are questions that are missing any sort of tag whatsoever. Either the question was migrated here and there were no tags that matched from the sending system, it uses a tag that only had one use and was thus dropped, or some other weirdness. Please tag appropriately.
- <s>[tags](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tags)
  Variously used on questions about tagging people in photos, ID3 tags in music files, and Gmail labels.</s>
- <s>[tips](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tips)
  Meta tag. By and large seems to be either questions asking for tips how to use Android or are open-ended questions that should be closed.</s>
- [html5](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/html5)
  Not sure what's going on here. At the very least should be tagged instead with [html](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/html), but that tag is problematic too.
- <s>[history](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history)
  Meta tag.</s>
- [macros](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/macros)
  Would seem to be covered by the [automation](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/automation) tag. Probably need a synonym here.
- See also:

  - **[Help needed in the [applications] tag](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/678/help-needed-in-the-applications-tag)**
  - [Carrier tag cleanup](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1418/carrier-tag-cleanup)
  - [Manufacturer tag cleanup](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1140/manufacturer-tag-cleanup)
  - [URL shortener clean-up project](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1572/url-shortener-clean-up-project)
  - [Misspelling cleanup](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1589/misspelling-cleanup)

---

**You can help!**

### Important

Do not simply fix the tag and nothing else. Very often there are multiple inappropriate tags, not to mention there are almost always spelling, grammar, and/or formatting issues to be addressed. **Fix the whole question**. While you're at it, check any answers on the question for similar issues.

On the other hand, don't bother fixing questions that should be closed and/or deleted. Just vote/flag them as appropriate.

**Remember: we don't migrate crap.**

#### Pro-tip #1

If you are removing tags from a large number of questions, it's better to go to the last question on the last page of all questions with that tag and work your way backwards. This prevents you from having to deal with the cache not reflecting your edits on the question list combined with browser-cache issues.

If you haven't visited most of these questions, you'll know what you changed because the link for the question will have a different color.

#### Pro-tip #2

Please edit in small batches and be mindful of front-page flooding – we don't want the entire front page to be filled with edits of old questions. Do three or five edits at a time, then come back later.

---

Let us know when a tag has been cleaned up. Even better, let us know about tags you think need cleaning.

Comment: [tag:voice] is all cleaned up

Comment: 'Tips' should now be clear

Comment: 'Tags' should now also be clear

Comment: 'History' now clear also

Comment: This question can be closed because it is no longer relevant.