# Tag cleanup for November, 2013

Tags: discussion, tag-cleanup

The following tags are overly broad, misapplied, *meta tags* [<sup>1</sup>](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1284/what-are-meta-tags)[<sup>2</sup>](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/), ambiguous or are otherwise problematic.

- [untagged](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged)
  These are questions that are missing any sort of tag whatsoever. Either the question was migrated here and there were no tags that matched from the sending system, it uses a tag that only had one use and was thus dropped, or some other weirdness. Please tag appropriately.
- [html5](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/html5)
  Not sure what's going on here. At the very least should be tagged instead with [html](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/html), but that tag is problematic too.
- <s>[macros](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/macros)
  Would seem to be covered by the [automation](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/automation) tag. Probably need a synonym here.</s>
- See also:

  - **[Help needed in the [applications] tag](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/678/help-needed-in-the-applications-tag)**
  - [Carrier tag cleanup](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1418/carrier-tag-cleanup)
  - [Manufacturer tag cleanup](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1140/manufacturer-tag-cleanup)
  - [URL shortener clean-up project](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1572/url-shortener-clean-up-project)
  - [Misspelling cleanup](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1589/misspelling-cleanup)

---

**You can help!**

### Important

Do not simply fix the tag and nothing else. Very often there are multiple inappropriate tags, not to mention there are almost always spelling, grammar, and/or formatting issues to be addressed. **Fix the whole question**. While you're at it, check any answers on the question for similar issues.

On the other hand, don't bother fixing questions that should be closed and/or deleted. Just vote/flag them as appropriate.

**Remember: we don't migrate crap.**

#### Pro-tip #1

If you are removing tags from a large number of questions, it's better to go to the last question on the last page of all questions with that tag and work your way backwards. This prevents you from having to deal with the cache not reflecting your edits on the question list combined with browser-cache issues.

If you haven't visited most of these questions, you'll know what you changed because the link for the question will have a different color.

#### Pro-tip #2

Please edit in small batches and be mindful of front-page flooding – we don't want the entire front page to be filled with edits of old questions. Do three or five edits at a time, then come back later.

---

Let us know when a tag has been cleaned up. Even better, let us know about tags you think need cleaning.

Comment: 'Untagged' is now clear

Comment: HTML5 adds various things like the <audio> and <video> tags, which I can see people asking about problems with from an end-user perspective.

Comment: Why wouldn't we cover that under "HTML"? We don't have tags for other versions of HTML.

Comment: I would imagine that we don't have tags for other versions of HTML because the previous version is almost 14 years old, so it can safely be assumed that if one talks about just "HTML", they mean "HTML 4.01".

Comment: Still and all, I don't think we need to distinguish between them on a site about _Android_. A site like Stack Overflow, sure. Heck, I'm not sure we even need the HTML tag.

Comment: Since we are not on a developer site, I think we can change all "html" and "htmlx" tagged questions to "browser" since it will be a browser problem (or a programming problem and so it doesn't belong here).

Comment: Macros is now clear

Comment: Untagged is clear again.

Comment: "Untagged" always comes back.