# Misspelling cleanup

Tags: discussion, clean-up

Here's another cleanup project to help improve the information on the site.

Fix common misspellings.

- [andriod](https://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=andriod) - Android
- [androind](https://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=androind) - Android
- [anroid](https://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=anroid) - Android
- [andoroid](https://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=andoroid) - Android
- [andorid](https://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=andorid) - Android
- [teh](https://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=teh) - the
- [parition](https://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=parition) - partition

**As with all clean-up projects, *don't just fix this one issue*. More than likely there are other issues with the post that should be addressed.**

And, as well, be aware of front-page flooding. Only fix a few posts at a time.

Comment: Well that's embarrassing, one of those mis-spellings was on one of my posts. Glad I got in to correct it before anyone else had to!

Comment: Feel free to add any other common misspellings you come across.

Comment: Added a couple more that I found in a few posts looking through the "andriod"s. Think I've got all the "parition"s but leaving it there in case they start coming back

Comment: "teh" is sometimes used ironically. I wouldn't edit out _all_ instances of it.

Comment: Fair warning to people with less than 2k reputation points: You risk having rejected as "too minor" edits that fix only one of these spelling errors and none of the other obvious problems with a post.